# Can Webots send real-time data to Simulink ？

Tags: matlab, simulink, webots

I want to use Simulink of MATLAB to calculate the foot trajectory and send the data to Webots to execute. Meanwhile, Webots send the data which measurd by sensors in robot to Simulink and modify the controller. Can I realize it? Is there a more simple way?
Should I use ADAMS instead of Webots？

Answer (score 1):

Webots has a Matlab API:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-matlab

Using this Matlab API you should be able to communicate between Webots and Simulink.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there any examples that I can learn? I am new to Webots.....Thank you very much!

Comment: The tutorials are available for Matlab too. See for example: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-4-more-about-controllers